# How do I avoid splitting albums on Samsung's default music app?

Tags: music-player, samsung-galaxy-s7

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7. I am trying to organize music in the default music app and running into some issues. For example, no matter how much I try and group music into one album or to one artist (on both the phone and my computer), songs are split up by each individual contributing artist to an album.

[image: Image of songs and albums split up]

How do I avoid splitting albums on Samsung's default music app?

Comment: Probably due the way music app is made. I don't think you can change it.

Answer (score 1):

Fill in the "album artist" field and make it identical for album fragments you want to see as one.